# LINQ select with in a select

Tags: c#, linq, select

I have an SQL query and I am trying to query this in LINQ, but I am not
getting correct subquery result
SQL QUERY:

```
   SELECT  
  (1) query_no, 
 (view_supplier_ledger_ap.co_code) ,
 (view_knockoff_ap.year_src) ,
 (view_knockoff_ap.period_src) ,
 (view_knockoff_ap.vchrtype_src) ,
 (view_knockoff_ap. Amount),
 (SELECT Sum(view_knockoff_ap_b. Amount)

 FROM view_knockoff_ap 
 view_knockoff_ap_b  
 WHERE  
 ( view_knockoff_ap.year_src = view_knockoff_ap_b.year_src ) and  
 (view_knockoff_ap.period_src = view_knockoff_ap_b.period_src)
 payment_amount_sum
FROM view_supplier_ledger_ap,   
ap_custsupplier,
view_knockoff_ap,
WHERE
  (view_supplier_ledger_ap.doc_type <> 'ACP Bill') 
   and(view_supplier_ledger_ap.co_code  = ap_custsupplier.Cst_CO_CODE)
```

Now, here's the problem I am having. When I do a select within a select, the value of the AMOUNT_SUM  field that is returned on each object is incorrect :

```
  MY LINQ:

 var Query1 = (from LedAP in context.VIEW_SUPPLIER_LEDGER_AP
                 join cs in context.AP_CUSTSUPPLIER
                  join konckAP in context.VIEW_KNOCKOFF_AP
                  join viewallow in context.view_allowed_period_user
                         select new
                          {
                              LedAP.CO_CODE,
                              LedAP.SUP_CODE,
                              konckAP.AMOUNT,

                              AMOUNT_SUM = context.VIEW_KNOCKOFF_AP
                              .Where(x => (x.YEAR_SRC == x.YEAR_SRC) && 
                              (x.PERIOD_SRC == x.PERIOD_SRC))
                               .GroupBy(x => x.AMOUNT)
                               .Select(a => a.Sum(b => 
                                b.AMOUNT)).FirstOrDefault()
                                });
```

Comment: If you're better at SQL than LINQ then why not just use sql for the complex queries? There are no Entity Framework police that will come arrest you.

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by amount and then multiply by the number of times the item occurs by using Sum.  Suppose a group is $10.00 and there a five items in the group.  Then the sum is $50.00.  If this is what you want it would be more understandable by using a.Count() * a.Key

Anyway here is how I would do it :

```
var Query1 = (from LedAP in context.VIEW_SUPPLIER_LEDGER_AP
                 join cs in context.AP_CUSTSUPPLIER
                  join konckAP in context.VIEW_KNOCKOFF_AP.Where(x => (x.YEAR_SRC == x.YEAR_SRC) && 
                              (x.PERIOD_SRC == x.PERIOD_SRC))
                  join viewallow in context.view_allowed_period_user
                         select new
                          {
                              LedAP.CO_CODE,
                              LedAP.SUP_CODE,
                              konckAP.AMOUNT
                           }).GroupBy(x => x.Amount)
                           .Select(a => new {a.CO_CODE,
                              a.SUP_CODE,a.Key * a.Count()});
```